# Shipping either free or charge - Woo commerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shipping-method

I am working on an e-commerce site in Wordpress. I want the shipping in a way that when customer purchase for $100 shipping would be free otherwise I would charge $10 as shipping charge. 
To have this flow working, I have setup two shipping zones one for Free shipping if the amount is equal to or more than $100 and another shipping zone is for normal charge of $10. 
Now they are working properly. 
My issue is when I add products upto of $100 or more it shows me both the options in shipping as radio buttons. Where a customer has to select free shipping.
I want it automatically shows free shipping when total amount is $100 or more than this. 
Thanks in Advance. 
[image]

Answer (score -2):

Here is how we can achieve it.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_package_rates','test_overwrite_fedex',100,2);

function test_overwrite_fedex($rates,$package) {

  foreach ($rates as $rate) {

    // you can check for the cart amount if it is greater than the 100 then unset the package from rates and then return.

  }

  return $rates;

}
```